# Is photon emission density is same or random everytime?

Tags: photons, density, sensor

I want to know if photon density changes over time. By density, I mean number of photon hitting a surface in time. I am not asking about the direction of emission which is random. What I mean is that for example if on first second for example 10 photons hit the sensor, the other second in time will the number be same or close to same? i.e 9 or it will be random like 10 photon then 5 photons then 8 photons then 14 photons, i.e is the number vary over time? And rate of emission is also random?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_antibunching

Comment: Light has "shot noise" ..... if the intensity (do not use density) is 100 photons per sec the shot noise is srqt of 100 which is  10 .... and it is a Gaussian distribution so 10 = 1 sigma. So if you take a picture maybe you get 90 , maybe you get 110 .... but on average it is 100.  Or if you have a million pixels you need to average to see 100 ... each pixel be different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a constant light source and a photon counter, the number of photons in a certain amount of time will be a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). The number of photons will vary randomly over time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, so it means the source also emit random number photons each second based on it's power, i.e photon emission is not same for every second but different like 10 photons then 100,14,30,50 etc. Because i read somewhere photons are emitted randomly sometime few photons sometimes more photons, i.e it's alway random, excluding the directions ofcourse which are also random.

Comment: Yes the total amount emitted by the light source will also be a Poisson distribution. But you should look at the Wikipedia page for Poisson distribution to see what values are reasonable - the ones you gave are very unlikely to arise from a Poisson distribution. The standard deviation will be the square root of the average number. So 10,8,14,11,9 would be a more reasonable sequence. Or 100,115, 95,107 for a light source emitting 10x as many photons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer so the distribution on the sensor will also be possion distribution as it was on the source of emission, again thanks for clearing up the confusion.

Comment: Light has "shot noise" ..... if the intensity (do not use density) is 100 photons per sec the shot noise is srqt of 100 which is 10 .... and it is a Gaussian distribution so 10 = 1 sigma. So if you take a picture maybe you get 90 , maybe you get 110 .... but on average it is 100. Or if you have a million pixels you need to average to see 100 ... each pixel be different.